# Is there any possibility to invoke managed methods from C in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

On the Windows Platform there's the possibility to create a COM wrapper around a managed object that might be used from unmanaged code.

Since I'm just dealing with a problem where I would like to pass a managed System.IO.Stream reference from managed code to a legacy C library function (its not even Objective-C), I'm curious if there's any chance at all to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't pass a managed reference like this to C code in iOS.

But you can do reverse P/Invoke calls: you give native code a delegate, and you can call that delegate from C as a function pointer.

Here is some (untested) sample code that should get you on the right track:

```
delegate long GetLengthCallback (IntPtr handle);

// Xamarin.iOS needs to the MonoPInvokeCallback attribute
// so that the AOT compiler can emit a method
// that can be called directly from native code.
[MonoPInvokeCallback (typeof (GetLengthCallback)]
static long GetLengthFromStream (IntPtr handle)
{
    var stream = (Stream) GCHandle.FromIntPtr (handle).Target;
    return stream.Length;
}

static List<object> delegates = new List<object> ();

static void SetCallbacks (Stream stream)
{
    NativeMethods.SetStreamObject (new GCHandle (stream).ToIntPtr ());

    var delGetLength = new GetLengthCallback (GetLengthFromStream);
    // This is required so that the GC doesn't free the delegate
    delegates.Add (delGetLength);
    NativeMethods.SetStreamGetLengthCallback (delGetLength);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: One additional question. How severe will the impact of the unmanaged to managed transition if the unmanaged code will invoke the Stream.Read delegate _very_ frequently for smaller chunks of data?

Comment: There is a significant impact for every transition, but if you care about that impact or not really depends on your app. My guess is that you won't notice much unless you call it thousands of times per second, but you need to measure to make sure. I would just go for the simple approach at first, and if it turns out to be a problem after profiling, you can easily improve it by adding some simple buffering in native code.